# QML: Get QObject parent

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qobject, qtquick2

QML introduces a separate ownership (`QObject`) tree from the visual tree (QtQuick scene graph).

- `parent` returns the visual parent.
- `children` returns the visual children.
- `data` returns the `QObject` children.

But how do I access the `QObject` parent?

FYI, I intend on dynamically creating and destroying nested layouts containing a custom type, so I need to manage the `QObject` tree - just using the visual tree will result in the 'wrong' objects disappearing after reparenting and then deleting.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't actually *know* the parent of the item, I don't think you can find out without going into C++. If you just want to *change* the item's `QObject` parent, you should be able to do so in QML by adding it to the `data` property of its new parent. (This will also change its visual parent, if applicable.)

Quoting the [the Qt Quick Concepts](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-visualparent.html) documentation:

> Any object assigned to an item's data property becomes a child of the item within its QObject hierarchy, for memory management purposes. Additionally, if an object added to the data property is of the Item type, it is also assigned to the Item::children property and becomes a child of the item within the visual scene hierarchy. (Most Qt Quick hierarchy crawling algorithms, especially the rendering algorithms, only consider the visual parent hierarchy.)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid unwanted ownership of objects by previous parents by creating them like this:

```
const someObject = someComponent.createObject( null, { parent: someItem });
```

This way `someItem` is only visual parent of `someObject`. You can move the child elsewhere then delete the container.

Comment: I know this is old, just leaving for next readers something I needed to find out myself.